# Python move dynamic subfolder one folder up

Tags: python, os.walk

We've got a fileshare that gets populated with flat files. The process extracting the files have extracted the files in a XYZ/YEAR/**DAY**/MONTH/x/y/z/files folder structure. This is wrong, since it needs to be in the following structure: XYZ/YEAR/**MONTH**/DAY/x/y/z/files. So, we need to create a migration script that somehow moves all the files from the old structure to the new structure.

Can someone give me some pointers how to do this with Python? I've been able to list all files and subdirectories using the os module but not sure how to move forward with shuffling the subfolders for day and month around to the target structure.

Thanks in advance!

I have to add: Its also fine to rename the month folder with the day folder and vice versa.

Comment: Are those all numbers?  That is, "XYZ/2021/17/11"?

Comment: I think the question you should ask is "how can I change the string `"XYZ/YEAR/DAY/MONTH/x/y/z/files"` to `"XYZ/YEAR/MONTH/DAY/x/y/z/files"`?". Once you figure this out, the question then becomes "how do I move all files from folder A to folder B?" Break a problem down into smaller parts, and it's easy to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.  This is somewhat dangerous, so you might want to comment out the `os.mkdir`, `os.rename`, and `os.rmdir` actions and replace them with print statements the first time around, just to make sure it's doing the right thing.

It's a tricky problem.  You can't just move "01" into the year directory, because there's already an "01" there for day 1.  Here, I create month directories with a prefix ("m01", "m02", etc), then move the contents, then remove the day directories and rename the month directories.

Now that I think of it, it might have been easier to create another "year" tree, but I think this will work.

```
import os

os.chdir( "XYZ" )


for year in os.listdir('.'):
    if not os.path.isdir(year):
        continue

    # Create month directories with an "m" prefix.

    for mon in range(1,13):
        os.mkdir( f"{year}/m{mon:02d}" )

    # For each day, move the contents.

    for day in os.listdir(year):
        yydd = os.path.join(year,day)
        if not os.path.isdir(yydd):
            continue
        for mon in os.listdir(yydd):
            yyddmm = os.path.join(year,day,mon)
            yymmdd = os.path.join(year,f"m{mon:02d}",day)
            os.mkdir( yymmdd )
            for part in os.listdir(yyddmm):
                os.rename( yyddmm+"/"+part, yymmdd )
    
    # Should now be able to delete the old structure for this year,
    # assuming they are empty.

    for day in os.listdir(year):
        if day[0] == 'm':
            continue
        yydd = os.path.join(year,day)
        for mon is os.listdir(yydd):
            os.rmdir( yydd+"/"+mon )
        os.rmdir( yydd )

    # Remove the prefix.

    for mon in range(1,13):
        os.rename( f"{year}/m{mon}", f"{year}/{mon}" )
```